# Problem with OpenCV on Kinetic

Tags: opencv, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am finding a way to resolve `OpenCV` issue with ROS Kinetic. After trying using `cvg_sim_gazebo` package, the functionality is now broken which previously was working. Is there any workaround to make it work, be it using `OpenCV2` or `OpenCV3`. I've also tried to use `OpenCV2` but I am restricted to `ros-kinetic-image-view` package and its dependencies.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281049/problem-with-opencv-on-kinetic/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2018-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-01-31**:
Please edit your question to include instructions how to setup your environment, what commands your running and the errors that your getting so we can help you.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2018-01-31**:
@tfoote: Thanks for your advise. I've just found a solution that re-installation fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out that after reinstalling the ROS solves the issue.

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1